# Should delegations propagate from one account to another?

Tags: democracy

Let's say Account A delegates to Account B and then Account B delegates to Account C. If Account C votes, Account B's vote is included, but not Account A's. And Account B or Account A cannot vote separately since they're delegating.

So, unbeknownst to Account A, their vote isn't included in the referendum. Should perhaps delegations propagate from one account to the other?

Otherwise, if we assume that Account A delegated to Account B with the premise that they'll make their own decisions, and as a result their delegation should **not** propagate, then:

- An account should not be allowed to delegate when they have other accounts delegating to them
- Or they should lose their delegations if they themselves delegate

Comment: Hmm... I could be wrong after all, because another test showed that the delegation does indeed propagate.

Comment: votes should propagate in the current design of polkadot governance. closing this as this is also not really a stackexchange question